# Regular Expressions pattern to extract particular digits from text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to extract phone numbers from a string in php using the `preg_match_all()` function. I know that this pattern `'!\d+!'` extracts all numbers. But i need it to do more.
The numbers i want to extract either start with 256 followed by 9 numbers or 078,077,071,079 followed by 8 numbers.
Thank you.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
\b(?:256\d{9}|07[17-9]\d{8})\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
\b(?:256\d{9}|07[17-9]\d{8})\b

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks; free-spacing

Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
Match the regular expression below «(?:256\d{9}|07[17-9]\d{8})»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «256\d{9}»
      Match the characters “256” literally «256»
      Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{9}»
         Exactly 9 times «{9}»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «07[17-9]\d{8}»
      Match the characters “07” literally «07»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[17-9]»
         The character “1” «1»
         A character in the range between “7” and “9” «7-9»
      Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{8}»
         Exactly 8 times «{8}»
Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not claim to be an expert with regex, but I tested one that works.

`(^(256[0-9]{9})|^(078|077|071|079)[0-9]{8})`

I tried it against the following:

```
256123456789
07812345678
07712345678
07112345678
07912345678
07212345678
```

Note the last one does not match one of the rules you said. The output matched all bu the last one.

Comment: Won't those parentheses cause it to capture "078" and the other 3-digit patterns as a match too?  I'm no expert either, but I was trying to figure out how to do this in the same fashion using square braces (no luck)

Comment: Ah yea, good point. I threw in the ^ delimiter to denote start of line.

Comment: Ah, so it's distributive, gotcha, thanks.

Comment: Use only one `^` but outside the brackets and you will also need the anchor for the end of the line `$` ==> `^((256[0-9]{9})|(078|077|071|079)[0-9]{8})$`

Comment: I see, say perhaps he wanted to match 256xxxx (string starting with 256) or match xxx078xxxx (string starting with anything), would you just put the ^ behind the 256 block?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
(256\d|07[17-9])\d{8}
```

[RegExr link](http://regexr.com?30reh)

Comment: Clever approach to only using `\d{8}`

Comment: You are missing anchors around your regex.

Comment: @KurzedMetal, This also finds the 3-digit capture groups (e.g. "078"), right?  Any idea how to return ONLY the full string?  I'm testing in JS web console using this: `"07800000000".match(/(256\d|078|077|071|079)\d{8}/);`

Comment: I just realized my answer is pretty similar to Cylian's.

Comment: @stema well anchors would be easy to add and he didn't specify any requirements about it. i don't know if they are supposed start at the beginning of the line, if they are quoted or separated by spaces.

Comment: @Marc adding `?:` to a group would make it non-capturing try changing the regex to `(?:256\d|07[17-9])\d{8}` and add parenthesis where necessary.

Comment: @KurzedMetal they are only easy to add for someone who knows regex. The OP wants the number to start with ... followed by x digits. So the only thing that is not clear from the question, is if he needs `\b` or `^$`.

Comment: @KurzedMetal, thanks for the response. I'm trying to get better at my regex, and StackOverflow questions like these are where I study.

Comment: @stema the regex actually doesn't need boundaries because i'm specifying the exact length. Boundaries are only needed when you use greedy operators. Look at this [example](http://regexr.com?30req)

Comment: @KurzedMetal, no thats not true. Your regex will also match 079123456781234. of course it will only match the part 07912345678, but thats not the number that has been found and it returns true.

Comment: @stema you are right, i'll just let the OP learn how to add a boundary.